# if and else statement not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

hello its really weird that a if and else statement is not working in my function even after the value comes in "no" then also the else part is executed instead of if  my code is

```
(function pollmsg() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var demon = $('.msgnotimore').val();
        alert(demon);
        var a = $('.gvpgvpxgvp').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'modules/notifications/beast.php?nid=' + demon + '&id=' + a,
            success: function (html) {
                if(html == "no") {
                    alert('no');
                } else {
                    alert('ok');
                    $('.msgnotimore').val();
                    $('.notiloadmsg').prepend($(html).fadeIn('slow'));
                }
            },
            dataType: "html",
            complete: pollmsg
        });
    }, 30000);
})();
});
```

i alerted html to check the value returning . its "no" but still the else part is working how is this possible ?

Comment: My guess is that you're not testing `html` properly. The value you're after is probably in a wrapper. Try using `console.log` instead of `alert`, or checking the `XHR` feed in developer tools to get the correct var to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try trimming html before doing the check.

```
if ($.trim(html) == 'no')
```

Comment: its 5am here in india and u saved me from being more awaken . thanks . its working awesome using trim :)